# как зафиксировать строки и столбцы?

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть div main, содержащий в себе div target. Как сделать при помощи flexbox так чтобы при изменении масштаба блоки target находились на своём месте?

http://68.183.70.133/game0711/game.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: р]

Comment: У тебя уже есть пример

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox внутри flexbox. Первый выравнивает поле по центру, второй задаёт порядок target'ов. Или тоже самое, но с grid'ами.